# Power BI non data driven matrix visual

Tags: matrix, powerbi

Currently I am working on a project to convert Excel reports into Power BI reports.

The excel reports is pretty much like below

```
|         |   Col1  |  Col2   |   Col3  |   Col4  |
| Row1    |Measure11|Measure12|Measure13|Measure14|
| Row2    |Measure21|Measure22|Measure23|Measure24|
| Row3    |Measure31|Measure32|Measure33|Measure34|
```

Where Rows and Columns are static, not data driven. It is pretty much similar to build a HTML table then place the corresponding measures in the  cells.

In the Power BI standard matrix, rows and columns are data driven. Though I can create a table to put the row name, column name in then write a measure using switch to retrieve the corresponding measure based on the row name and column name, it works fine but very hard to maintain considering this is a 11 x 30 matrix = 330 measures inside the switch statement.

Just wonder if there are any premium Power BI Visual can fulfil the requirements above. Thank you!

Comment: In the measure, you can get the value of your row and column header. Now, if you can implement all your logics based on those values, I think 1 single measure can fulfil your requirement.

Comment: The included Multi Row Card visual may be an option, or the Card (new) visual, both of these allow multiple measures to be added. With a bit of formatting it could come close to looking like a table. Do you need the measures to be reactive to slicers/filters or can they be static?